# how to update values in a input file? For exmaple the input file has a value of 10. How can the user change the value by cin a new value?

Tags: c++

This is what I tried. I tried strcpy, substituting the value and using in_file again 3 of them can't work. This program is supposed to use the data in a input file and then does functions 1-4 selected by user.

1. List all products
2. Search the price of a product
3. Update the price of a product
4. Exit
   If the user chooses to exit, the program will write the updated data in the array of structures to the file.
   The product information includes product number, description and price.

````
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    char product_num[5];
    char product_des[29];
    float price;
}PRODUCT_TYPE;

int main()
{
    ifstream in_file("input practical 12 part d.txt");
    if (!in_file)
    {
            cout << "Error opening input file" << endl;
    }
        
    else
    {
        PRODUCT_TYPE product[50];
        int index = -1;
        int choice;
        in_file >> product[++index].product_num;
        cout << "Succesful run" << endl;
        cout << "Menu (Type number for the function)" << endl;
        cout << "1. List all products\n2.Search the price of a product\n3.Update the price of a product\n4.Exit\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            cout << setw(18) << left << "Product Index" << setw(35) << left << "Product Description" << "Price" << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Enter the product number to change its price: ";
            cin >> product[index].product_num;
            cout << "Enter the new price of the product: ";
            cin >> product[index].price;
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            cout << setw(18) << left << "Product Index" << setw(35) << left << "Product Description" << "Price" << endl;
        }

        while (in_file)
        {
            in_file >> product[index].product_des >> product[index].price;
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                cout << setw(18) << left << product[index].product_num << setw(35) << left << product[index].product_des << product[index].price << endl;

            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                cout << "Type the product number to get the price" << endl;
                cout << "Product Number: ";
                cin >> product[index].product_num;
                cout << "Price: ";
                cout << product[index].price << endl;
            }
            
            else if (choice == 4)
            {
                cout << setw(18) << left << product[index].product_num << setw(35) << left << product[index].product_des << product[index].price << endl;
            }
            in_file >> product[++index].product_num;
        }
        in_file.close();
        out_file.close();
    }
    return 0;

}```
````

Comment: Unless you're using a fixed size record format for your file contents, read the file completely into the data structures you have, manipulate these, and wrtie them back into the file as a whole.

Comment: Also you should structure your code into separate functions: One for reading the file into the above mentioned array (use a `std::vector<PRODUCT_TYPE>` to realize that), another one for manipulation of a single `PRODUCT_TYPE` record in memory, another one for adding new records, etc., etc. This would help you to concentrate your programming efforts, to single, simpler tasks, you can solve one after another, without getting prone, to change or add a single thing and blow up what you already had working.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately changes in existing files are not that easy. The problem is that data are stored byte after byte in a file on a disk (sometimes even not that). So, if you have data in your file (always one byte) like the below

```
Position in file:    0 1 2  3  4  5  9  7  8 9 . . .  
Bytes as decimal:    . . . 49 50 51 61 62 63 . . .
Bytes as character:  . . .  1  2  3  A  B  C . . .
```

And you want to update 1 2 3 at position 3 by 1 2 3 4 5 then you would need to shift all folowing bytes in the file by 2 characters, because 12345 is 2 bytes longer than 123. Nobody can do that. And it will not be done automatically.

So, there are basically 2 approaches to solve such problems.

1. Open the source file -> Read all data into memory -> Close source file -> Do the modifications in memory -> Open source file in overwrite mode -> Write new data.
2. Use a temporary file. -> Open the source file for input -> Open a temporary file for output -> Read source file line by line -> Do modifications for each read line immediately -> Write result to temp file -> After all source file data have been read, close both files -> Delete the original source file. Rename the tempfile to the old source file name.

(3. If the length of the data, that you want to modifiy, is the same than the old data, then you could move the file write pointer and overwrite the old data. But you need always the same length. So, most often not feasible)

There are of course more solutions, but those 2 approaches are often used.

Please see some pure example codes. Just plain example, unrelated to your code. No productive code. No error checking. Just to give you an idea, how it could work.

Method 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> readFile(const std::string& filename) {

    // Here we will store all the data from the file
    std::vector<std::string> fileData;

    // Open the source file
    std::ifstream fileStream(filename);

    // Read line by line and add it to our fileData
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(fileStream, line)) {

        fileData.push_back(line);
    }
    return fileData;
}

void writeFile(std::vector<std::string>& fileData, const std::string& filename) {

    // Open file for output
    std::ofstream fileStream(filename);

    // Write all data to file
    for (const std::string& line : fileData)
        fileStream << line << '\n';
}

int main() {

    // Aproach with read complete file to local variable, modify and the store again
    const std::string dataFileName("r:\\test.txt");

    // Get file content
    std::vector<std::string> data = readFile(dataFileName);


    // Now go through all records and do something
    for (std::string& line : data) {

        // If some condition is met then do something, for example modify
        if (line == "Line1") line += " modified";
    }


    // And then write the new data to the file
    writeFile(data, dataFileName);

    return 0;
}
```

Method 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    // Aproach with temp file, remove and rename, and on the fly change

    const std::string dataFileName("r:\\test.txt");
    const std::string tempFileName("r:\\temp.txt");

    {
        // Open the source file with data
        std::ifstream dataFileStream(dataFileName);

        // Open the temporary file for output
        std::ofstream tempFileStream(tempFileName);

        // Now read the source file line by line with a simple for loop
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(dataFileStream, line)) {

            // Identify the line that should be deleted and do NOT write it to the temp file
            if (line != "SearchString") {  // Or any other condition

                // Write only, if the condition is not met
                tempFileStream << line << '\n';
            }
        }
    } // The end of the scope for the streams, will call their destructor and close the files

    // Now, remove and rename
    std::remove(dataFileName.c_str());
    std::rename(tempFileName.c_str(), dataFileName.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the idea is creating a temp file with updated information, and then remove the old file and rename the temp file to the old file? I managed to create a temp file but I don't understand how to remove and rename the file as you showed. Can you clarify it with an example? And is it ok to rename the temp file to the old file and rename the old file to the temp file so the user don't need to create a new temp file every time the user needs to modify something? Thanks

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. That is the idea. How to remove and rename is shown in the last 2 lines of the 2nd example. Renaming the temp file to the old file (after the old file was deleted) is ok. And no. Do nothing else.